# Overriding Leaflet tooltip style?

Tags: leaflet, css

I'd like to override the default style of Leaflet 1.0.0 tooltips, especially the bubble/frame. I don't see any options or methods for this. How do I hook into the CSS? I want to change layers individually, so I need to select each layer's tooltips individually with CSS.

Answer (score 22):

The `L.Tooltip` class includes a `className` option (inherited from the `DivOverlay` class), which will be converted into a CSS class when the tooltip is displayed. e.g.:

```
L.marker(latlng).addTo(map).bindTooltip('Text', {className: 'myCSSClass'});
```

Then, it's just a matter of defining that CSS class. The tip is a bit tricky, as it needs working with pseudo-elements and leaflet CSS classes:

```
.myCSSClass {
  background: green;
  border: 2px solid cyan
}
.leaflet-tooltip-left.myCSSClass::before {
  border-left-color: cyan;
}
.leaflet-tooltip-right.myCSSClass::before {
  border-right-color: cyan;
}
```

[See a working example here](https://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/ran/1/edit?html,output).

Comment: OK, I'll write out a full class for each layer and attach via that option. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible, though, to "reset" the CSS for *all* layers' labels, ie to remove the border/bgcolor? The individual styles I attach via classname could then only have the extra declarations required.

Comment: Just seen your updated answer. I'll try `.leaflet-tooltip`, and its `-left` and `-right` classes, with the pseudo-elements, and see where I get, Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, you are free to inspect and overwrite the CSS rules which apply to `.leaflet-tooltip` (and `-left` and `-right`). Just make sure you do that *after* loading the Leaflet CSS.

Comment: To modify the little right or left pointing triangle edit the `::before` class. Ex: to hide it altogether: `.leaflet-tooltip-left.myCSSClass::before {border-left-color: transparent;}` (Took me a long time to figure that out)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the comments above which focus on the pointed arrow part of the tooltip component, I also had some luck with:

```
.leaflet-tooltip {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0px;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Otherwise, I was still seeing the outline of the tooltip with a white (default) background, black (default) border and a box-shadow which itself appears as a border.