# How to label geojson points in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, geojson

How to show labels for geojson points in a Leaflet map?

There is [Leaflet.label](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.label) that is now deprecated in favour of [L.Tooltip](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.1.0.html#tooltip), but that only shows text on hover. I want to show the text labels directly on the map without needing user interaction.

Sample input - https://gist.github.com/maphew/e168430e999fc738eeb3448feda121cd

Desired result (green points with text labels, the other graphic elements are just for context):

[image: simulated map of points with text labels]

**Update:** I want to create text that blends in with the map like the image below, not a popup tooltip.

[image: image with unwanted part crossed out]

Comment: Just use the tooltip option `permanent`? From http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.1.0.html#tooltip-option : `Whether to open the tooltip permanently or only on mouseover`

Comment: Use `L.Marker`s with `L.DivIcon`s.

Comment: If you can't solve this purely in Leaflet, an option could be to put your points in GeoServer (or similar) and load them as a [WMS tile layer](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.1.0.html#tilelayer-wms) whereby the style shows [labels](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/cookbook/points.html#point-with-styled-label). In [this example](http://i.imgur.com/bMYbUe6.png) the blue labels are achieved in this manner

Comment: @IvanSanchez I can't get that to work. The custom html is not coming through. See my attempt at https://jsfiddle.net/maphew/q0refcwx/1/

Answer (score 24):

Here's an implementation following @BradHards suggestion of using the `permanent` option for tooltip. The `opacity` option fades both text and background container equally.

```
var data_points = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "name": "test-points-short-named",
    "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
    "features": [
    { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "name": "1" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -135.02507178240552, 60.672508785052223 ] } },
    { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "name": "6"}, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -135.02480935075292, 60.672888247036376 ] } },
    { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "name": "12"}, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -135.02449372349508, 60.672615176262731 ] } },
    { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "name": "25"}, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -135.0240752514004, 60.673313811878423 ] } }
    ]};

var pointLayer = L.geoJSON(null, {
  pointToLayer: function(feature,latlng){
    label = String(feature.properties.name) // Must convert to string, .bindTooltip can't use straight 'feature.properties.attribute'
    return new L.CircleMarker(latlng, {
      radius: 1,
    }).bindTooltip(label, {permanent: true, opacity: 0.7}).openTooltip();
    }
  });
pointLayer.addData(data_points);
mymap.addLayer(pointLayer);
```

[image: screenshot]

Full working example: https://jsfiddle.net/maphew/gtdkxj8e/3/

#### To remove the label background

See [Overriding Leaflet tooltip style?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/212820/overriding-leaflet-tooltip-style) for details modifying the CSS and [Removing tooltip label border completely in Leaflet.js map?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241739/removing-tooltip-label-border-completely-in-leaflet-js-map) for removing the triangle pointer without touching the CSS (simply add `direction: "center"` to `.bindTooltip`!)

Javascript:

```
.bindTooltip(label, {permanent: true, 
   direction: "center",
   className: "my-labels"}).openTooltip();
```

CSS:

```
.leaflet-tooltip.my-labels {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
  }
```

[image: screenshot: labels with no container graphics]

Full working example: https://jsfiddle.net/maphew/gtdkxj8e/7/

Comment: If you do take this route you can change css of tooltips or add classname (tooltip inherits from divoverlay) to the tooltip to remove the background colors, borders, shadows, etc. ie. `.leaflet-tooltip {background-color: transparent;border: transparent;}`

Comment: Thank you @Diffusion_net! those keywords led me to related questions and to a more complete solution (now added to answer).

Comment: This is a 2017 solution, **some 2022 news?** (strange seems nothing on [leafletjs.com reference](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html)...)

Comment: @PeterKrauss In 2022 answer would be the same, see https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tooltip