# Override Tooltip Style in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, css

I'm trying to override the tooltip style of Leaflet 1.3.1.and want to completely remove the tooltip pointer as shown in figure.[image: tip pointer]

This is my css:

```
.ToolTipProvince{
          font-size: 15px;
                font-weight:bold;
                padding: 0px;
                background: none;
                border: none;
                color: aqua;
                text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
                box-shadow: none;
            outline: none;
        }
```

and applying style to layer tooltip:

```
layer.bindTooltip("Province Number: "+feature.properties.PROVINCE+"", {permanent: true, direction: 'centre', className: 'ToolTipProvince'});
```

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/212820/overriding-leaflet-tooltip-style?rq=1  might help.

Comment: Also, don't use `L.Tooltip` when you want to use a `L.DivIcon`

Comment: @IvanSanchez first of all i want to clear that it's not a duplicate. I have gone through that question before asking it here, the context is different.